# ScrollView no funciona : ScrollView can host only one direct child

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Buena tarde, estoy intentado agregar un `ScrollView` pero no esta funcionando,  el archivo `xml` es:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="20dp"
tools:context="matgic.com.matgic.MainActivity"
>

<ScrollView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:scrollbars="vertical">

<TextView
   android:id="@+id/selidio"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textColor="#faf8f8"
   android:text="@string/sel_idio"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:textSize="30sp"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   />

<TextView
   android:id="@+id/sellan"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textColor="#fcfbfb"
   android:text="@string/sel_lan"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:textSize="30sp"
   android:layout_below="@id/selidio"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  />


<ImageButton
   android:id="@+id/es"
   android:layout_width="150dp"
   android:layout_height="150dp"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
   app:srcCompat="@drawable/espaniol"
/>

<ImageButton
   android:id="@+id/en"
   android:layout_width="150dp"
   android:layout_height="150dp"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
   app:srcCompat="@drawable/english"
/>
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Este error despliega en `Stack Trace`:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child
>       at android.widget.ScrollView.addView(ScrollView.java:279)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:867)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:866)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:325)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:384)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:193)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:547)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$3(RenderTask.java:681)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: A mi, me sucedió algo parecido. En mi caso, tenia dos Linearloyout en el código. Uno, para organizar la imagen y los textos debajo en vertical, y el otro para organizar dos botones en horizontal. Sin embargo, me toco dejar solo un Linearlayout, y los botones, los ubique con otros métodos. Esto me soluciono el problema. Escribo esto, para que sepan, que también puede aparecer el error si intentan utilizar un scrollview, con mas de un Linearloyout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso pasa porque el scroll view solo puede tener un hijo

Tu en este caso tienes los siguientes hijos:

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/selidio"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textColor="#faf8f8"
   android:text="@string/sel_idio"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:textSize="30sp"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   />

<TextView
   android:id="@+id/sellan"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textColor="#fcfbfb"
   android:text="@string/sel_lan"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:textSize="30sp"
   android:layout_below="@id/selidio"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  />


<ImageButton
   android:id="@+id/es"
   android:layout_width="150dp"
   android:layout_height="150dp"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
   app:srcCompat="@drawable/espaniol"
/>

<ImageButton
   android:id="@+id/en"
   android:layout_width="150dp"
   android:layout_height="150dp"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
   app:srcCompat="@drawable/english"
/>
```

En total son 4.

Lo que puedes hacer es meter esos cuatro hijos a un Relative Layout, para que sea el unico hijo del scroll view y los 4 hijos pasen a ser hijos del relative.

De la siguiente forma:

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
       android:id="@+id/selidio"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textColor="#faf8f8"
       android:text="@string/sel_idio"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:textSize="30sp"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       />

    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/sellan"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textColor="#fcfbfb"
       android:text="@string/sel_lan"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:textSize="30sp"
       android:layout_below="@id/selidio"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      />


    <ImageButton
       android:id="@+id/es"
       android:layout_width="150dp"
       android:layout_height="150dp"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       app:srcCompat="@drawable/espaniol"
    />

    <ImageButton
       android:id="@+id/en"
       android:layout_width="150dp"
       android:layout_height="150dp"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       app:srcCompat="@drawable/english"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Espero te ayude :)

Comment: Gracias @Brayan Armando, esa fue la solución

Answer (score 1):

La descripción del error indica el problema,

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child

en español sería:

> **java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView puede alojar solo un hijo directo**

**No puedes agregar varios elementos dentro de un `ScrollView`, en cambio puedes agregar un contenedor (layout) y este puede contener varios elementos al mismo tiempo.**

Ejemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="20dp"
tools:context="matgic.com.matgic.MainActivity">

<ScrollView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_contenedor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

         // ... Agregar aquí elementos!!! 

    </RelativeLayout>

   </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

Este sería el código del layout completo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="20dp"
tools:context="matgic.com.matgic.MainActivity">

<ScrollView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_contenedor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

         <TextView
   android:id="@+id/selidio"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textColor="#faf8f8"
   android:text="@string/sel_idio"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:textSize="30sp"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<TextView
   android:id="@+id/sellan"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textColor="#fcfbfb"
   android:text="@string/sel_lan"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:textSize="30sp"
   android:layout_below="@id/selidio"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>


<ImageButton
   android:id="@+id/es"
   android:layout_width="150dp"
   android:layout_height="150dp"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
   app:srcCompat="@drawable/espaniol"/>

<ImageButton
   android:id="@+id/en"
   android:layout_width="150dp"
   android:layout_height="150dp"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
   app:srcCompat="@drawable/english"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

   </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Gracias @Jorgesys esa fue la solución

Comment: Hola Sergio @Sergio , excelente, saludos!